# How to attach a process in eclipse for debugging of muiti-process program

Tags: c, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, gdb

As my title say, I am having trouble in debugging my source code which is multi-process program.
This is as following:
1. The program is written to be daemon process, so the parent/main process is a daemon process.
2. It forks a number of child processes, around 5 to 7 or 8 process.

I use eclipse to develop my code, and I want to debug my program from eclipse.
As far as I tried, the debugger does not know the breakpoints from child process.

Thus I would like to know, Is there any option available by which I can debug my program, including child processes?
Is there any setting in eclipse by which I can attach the child pid so that debugger switch to that child process?

Such as, assume child pids 4523, 4562, 5462.Then during debug time, can I attach debugger to 5462 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhat related. I totally ghetto'ed a solution for a similar situation when writing add-ins for a Domino server years ago. Ultimately I ended up temporary changing the fork-code to double fork and execvp an xterm configured to launch gdb, attaching to the child process who's id I had slurped on the initial fork. It was hideous, but it worked *remarkably* well for catching a fault buried deep in the add-in. I would think by now eclipse would have a configuration for gdb the enable debugging child processes by this time (that was 12 years ago).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your information,And yes, eclipse Kepler now support for debugging child processes, But currently as I tried it is possible for one child.And because my program is daemon, so I think this also is a restriction for eclipse to debug, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4):

See the gdb `follow-fork-mode` setting. With this option you can control gdb behavior when the process forks. You can set it from gdb console

```
gdb> set follow-fork-mode child
```

So in fork gdb will switch to the child process. Another possible value here is to follow `parent`. If you want to debug them both from one gdb session, use this option:

```
gdb> set detach-on-fork off
```

This will make the debugger open a new inferior for the child process. Later you can switch between them like this:

```
gdb> inferior 1
```

Another way to do this is just to attach to a new process from another gdb session.

Update: I always use gdb from console, so I don't know if there any gdb settings in eclipse, maybe someone else will help you with gui options. If you have a gdb console in eclipse, you can try this commands there.

Update 2: see [this link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) about gdb fork options.